# Guide to action client state ID numbers

Tags: ros, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing an action server, and I got an unhelpful error message:

```
/my_action_server set_canceled:120: To transition to a cancelled state, the goal must be in a pending, recalling, active, or preempting state, it is currently in state: 2
```

The message is unhelpful becasue I don't know what state "2" is. I've found this [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib/DetailedDescription)  about action servers, but it doesn't say which state is "2".

I would like to know the indices of the various states so that I can debug my action server.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271257/guide-to-action-client-state-id-numbers/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that it's in the `PREEMPTED` state. According to the [message definition](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalStatus.html) found at the api:

```
GoalID goal_id
uint8 status
uint8 PENDING         = 0   # The goal has yet to be processed by the action server
uint8 ACTIVE          = 1   # The goal is currently being processed by the action server
uint8 PREEMPTED       = 2   # The goal received a cancel request after it started executing
                            #   and has since completed its execution (Terminal State)
uint8 SUCCEEDED       = 3   # The goal was achieved successfully by the action server (Terminal State)
... # edited for brevity
```

It's a constant. You can always find this sort of information out by running

```
$ rosmsg show actionlib_msgs/GoalState
```

but just change `actionlib_msgs/GoalState` with whatever message you're trying to examine.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2